# Citing ONLY with a number without changing citestyle

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a number of books, articles, ... in my text. I have set the biblatex configuration to

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  citestyle=authortitle
]{biblatex}
```

Because in the introduction, I refer to existing papers easily by using `\cite{bib:key}` and it gives me the author and the title. But now I want to also cite such that it only gives the number as given in the `\printbibliography` command such that I can literally cite text out of an article and then simply give the reference number to which it belongs without giving the entire author and title again. How can this be done?

Comment: You could stick with the alphabetic citestyle and `\citeauthor` and `\citetitle` for the citations in the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you stick with `style=alphabetic,` and define a new command for citations in the abstract. For author-title citations in the abstract we can just copy the relevant code from `authortitle.cbx` and rename macros to avoid name clashes.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{atcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{atcite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{atcite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{at:citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{atcite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{atcite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{atcite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{atcite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\atcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{atcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\atcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{at:citetitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\patcite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{atcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\patcite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{at:citetitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Lorem \patcite{nussbaum} ipsum \atcite{geer}
\end{abstract}

\section{Real text}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Nussbaum, Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’) ipsum Geer, ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music’//[SR98; Wor02]]